Select the best matching for set of rows and use each value only once, e.g. unique paring
I have input data
# |                column1                |            column2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 |  3ed28be1-92a0-4cf0-a258-a0e248f9a15c | 8bc73931-fc5a-488e-9fa3-60fce65cf427
2 |  3ed28be1-92a0-4cf0-a258-a0e248f9a15c | b5861526-1ed2-4030-9064-333abb902da7
3 |  4c300c60-b4c0-4c9c-9d7d-081a503786ed | 5f04a419-fc0d-4683-a2f9-06abc2c18218
4 |  61ffe19a-91be-4649-8c31-607523798b39 | 8bc73931-fc5a-488e-9fa3-60fce65cf427
5 |  61ffe19a-91be-4649-8c31-607523798b39 | b5861526-1ed2-4030-9064-333abb902da7
6 |  67c28846-e602-4f44-aba4-f9372a38101f | 5f04a419-fc0d-4683-a2f9-06abc2c18218
7 |  7b3b0d03-b81b-4202-9ef4-39eafd99d176 | 8bc73931-fc5a-488e-9fa3-60fce65cf427
8 |  7b3b0d03-b81b-4202-9ef4-39eafd99d176 | b5861526-1ed2-4030-9064-333abb902da7

and I need SQL query (Postgres) that finds all matches and uses each value only once on both sides. In other words I need to filter out all duplications on both sides but at the same time I need to keep as many records as possible.
For above example correct answer is:
# |                column1                |            column2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 |  3ed28be1-92a0-4cf0-a258-a0e248f9a15c | 8bc73931-fc5a-488e-9fa3-60fce65cf427
3 |  4c300c60-b4c0-4c9c-9d7d-081a503786ed | 5f04a419-fc0d-4683-a2f9-06abc2c18218
5 |  61ffe19a-91be-4649-8c31-607523798b39 | b5861526-1ed2-4030-9064-333abb902da7

or
# |                column1                |            column2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2 |  3ed28be1-92a0-4cf0-a258-a0e248f9a15c | b5861526-1ed2-4030-9064-333abb902da7
3 |  4c300c60-b4c0-4c9c-9d7d-081a503786ed | 5f04a419-fc0d-4683-a2f9-06abc2c18218
4 |  61ffe19a-91be-4649-8c31-607523798b39 | 8bc73931-fc5a-488e-9fa3-60fce65cf427

Any ideas?

A query that "finds all matches"? What is this supposed to mean here? What matches what? It seems you simply want to filter rows, so that your result contains some of the original rows, such that all values are shown, no matter whether at the left or the right hand side and you have no value repeated. So what if there is an uneven number of values in the table? What if such a combination is not possible (e.g., there only exists the rows 1|2, 1|3, 1|4)? What to show in such constellations?

If we have rows 1|2, 1|3, 1|4 then any of them is the correct result. Yes, I need to filter out duplications on both sides, but I need to keep as many as possible.

@AndriiParfonov: After all you added, you have a very different setup than I understood your question at first glance. Could you please edit and improve your question? I think you should explain more detailed the expected logic and build up the sample data as shown in your new fiddle. This will prevent lots of confusion. I will remove my answer and maybe write a new one.

@AndriiParfonov, your fiddle have 12 possible variants. Please see (https://dbfiddle.uk/8zEY8Fng). Please comment on this decision.

I've made your new data more visible. (https://dbfiddle.uk/UlnhwKzj)

I just edited my answer, seeing the discussion and comments.Hope my understanding is correct, otherwise let us know

Possible combinations is (1,3,5),(2,3,4),(1-3-8) and so on.

I think it is necessary to carry out a complete search of possible combinations here (through a recursive query).
Other options are unreliable, because it is completely unknown what conditions are set for the formation of the source table.
Query steps.

Recursively collect all possible combinations of rows (path).
Take rows with max path length. For example if we have output as
(1,3),(1,5),(3,1),(3,5),(5,1),(5,3) and (1,3,5),(1,5,3) ... we take rows
with path length=3.
For path's like (1,3,5),(1,5,3),(5,3,1) we convert path string to table and aggregate back. For all above path we get (1,3,5).
Take first (any) of above rows.
Join source table on Id in path.

CREATE TABLE test (id int, v1 varchar(10), v2 varchar(10));

INSERT INTO test VALUES 
(1,'test1','test2'),
(2,'test3','test4'),
(3,'test5','test4'),
(4,'test3','test2'),
(5,'test5','test2'),
(6,'test5','test6'),
(7,'test3','test6')
--(8,'test6','test7'),
--(9,'test7','test8')
;




id
v1
v2




1
test1
test2


2
test3
test4


3
test5
test4


4
test3
test2


5
test5
test2


6
test5
test6


7
test3
test6



with recursive r as(
  select 1 lvl,id, v1,v2
    ,concat('-',v1,'-',v2,'-') listV
    ,concat('-',id,'-') path
  from test
  union all
  select lvl+1 lvl,r.id, t.v1,t.v2
    ,concat(r.listV,'-',t.v1,'-',t.v2,'-') listV
    ,concat(r.path,t.id,'-') path
  from r  inner join test t
     on strpos(path,concat('-',t.id,'-'))=0
       and strpos(r.listV,concat('-',t.v1,'-'))=0
       and strpos(r.listV,concat('-',t.v2,'-'))=0
)
select *
from( -- take  one for variants
  select * ,row_number()over(order by idsordered) variantN
  from( -- take one row for idsordered 
    select * ,row_number()over(partition by idsordered)rn
    from ( -- take rows with max level of recursion
      select *  ,max(lvl)over() maxlvl
      from r
    )
  cross join lateral -- unpack id-path and pack again with id order
    ( select string_agg(idn,'-' order by idn) idsordered
      from(
        select * from string_to_table(path,'-') idn 
        where length(idn)>0
         )agr
     ) ids
  where lvl=maxlvl 
  )b
  where rn=1
)c
left join test v on strpos(path,concat('-',v.id,'-'))>0 ;




lvl
id
v1
v2
listv
path
maxlvl
idsordered
rn
variantn
id
v1
v2




3
1
test3
test4
-test1-test2--test5-test6--test3-test4-
-1-6-2-
3
1-2-6
1
1
1
test1
test2


3
1
test3
test4
-test1-test2--test5-test6--test3-test4-
-1-6-2-
3
1-2-6
1
1
2
test3
test4


3
1
test3
test4
-test1-test2--test5-test6--test3-test4-
-1-6-2-
3
1-2-6
1
1
6
test5
test6


3
7
test1
test2
-test3-test6--test5-test4--test1-test2-
-7-3-1-
3
1-3-7
1
2
1
test1
test2


3
7
test1
test2
-test3-test6--test5-test4--test1-test2-
-7-3-1-
3
1-3-7
1
2
3
test5
test4


3
7
test1
test2
-test3-test6--test5-test4--test1-test2-
-7-3-1-
3
1-3-7
1
2
7
test3
test6



fiddle
Update1.  Fiddle with new test data from OP.
fiddle.

I tried to add some data and looked at how the examples shown in the answers of colleagues to this question work. As expected, there are such variants of the source data that lead to an incomplete answer. (https://dbfiddle.uk/QuYljHAF).

Without understanding the principles of data formation (possible combinations of data pairs), it is difficult to assert something confidently.

Data is UUID, as I said in other thread I provided text data in my question to make the example more readable, which was probably not a good idea and caused even more complications.

I think using simplified data for an example is the right decision. Then it is quite possible to convert query to the original data type.

EDITED with UUID
I start by adding the first row with id1 as it was never seen before, I then proceed to the subsequent rows and check whether any of the value in column1 or column2 were seen before, if not append to the output , if yes proceed to the next row.
Lastly limit the output depending on whichever column has minimum distinct values.
Fiddle
WITH RECURSIVE unique_pairs AS (
    SELECT 
        id, 
        column1, 
        column2, 
        ARRAY[column1]::VARCHAR[] AS used_column1, 
        ARRAY[column2]::VARCHAR[] AS used_column2
    FROM 
        my_table
    WHERE 
        id = 1
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT 
        t.id, 
        t.column1, 
        t.column2, 
        up.used_column1 || t.column1, 
        up.used_column2 || t.column2
    FROM 
        my_table t
    JOIN 
        unique_pairs up
    ON 
        t.id > up.id
    WHERE 
        NOT t.column1 = ANY(up.used_column1) 
        AND NOT t.column2 = ANY(up.used_column2)
)
SELECT 
    id, 
    column1, 
    column2
FROM 
    unique_pairs
ORDER BY 
    id
LIMIT (
    SELECT LEAST(
        (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column1) FROM my_table),
        (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column2) FROM my_table)
    )
);

Output
| id | column1                              | column2                              |
| 1  | 3ed28be1-92a0-4cf0-a258-a0e248f9a15c | 8bc73931-fc5a-488e-9fa3-60fce65cf427 |
| 3  | 4c300c60-b4c0-4c9c-9d7d-081a503786ed | 5f04a419-fc0d-4683-a2f9-06abc2c18218 |
| 5  | 61ffe19a-91be-4649-8c31-607523798b39 | b5861526-1ed2-4030-9064-333abb902da7 |


Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately it doesn't cover all combination. For instance, if I comment out two lines in insert statement here https://dbfiddle.uk/GY8pjhas then query produces duplicates in column1. I'm afraid this is is hardly possible to solve in SQL. Even if it is possible, I don't like to add such complexity to application. This is already solved in peace of Java code, easy and reliable.

@AndriiParfonov yes it will only cover one of the many combinations since you mentioned either of them is correct and also I dont see any commented lines in your fiddle link.To include all correct combinations you need to first find all the possible combinations by iterating which is not the approach taken here.I agree with you that the simpler approach should be choosen for the implementation part since it helps in maintenance.
And you could have given us headsup about the option of Java, so we could have thought about it as an option since the start.

If you are new around here, this might help
=> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

I cannot share Java code but I have translated it to Groovy. With Groovy it is event better because you can play with it online http://tpcg.io/_0II7VT.
Java code even simpler since sorting is part of SQL but it contains domain part and it is difficult to share exact code.
